# Deprecation Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated

Tags: civimember

Im getting this error while trying to update a membership record.

The console shows

jquery.min.js:4 POST https://mysite.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontact%2Fview%2Fmembership&action=update&cid=2400&id=3151&context=membership&selectedChild=member&snippet=json 500

Comment: Not sure if you're the same person but this looks like it was also posted as https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/membership/-/issues/39. Look in the web server error logs to see the real error.